# Allocator runs out of memory even on very low batch sizes

Tags: memory, tensorflow, keras, gpu

This problem never used to occur but since today Tensorflow always tries to allocate a huge amount of memory, even when using very small batch sizes.

I followed this tutorial:

https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

"Using the bottleneck features of a pre-trained network: 90% accuracy in a minute"

This is my code:

```python
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import applications


img_width, img_height = 150, 150

top_model_weights_path = 'bottleneck_fc_model.h5'
train_data_dir = 'C:\\ImageData\\Augmented\\Train'
validation_data_dir = 'C:\\ImageData\\Augmented\\Validate'
#train_data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\NSA\\flower_photos\\Train'
#validation_data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\NSA\\flower_photos\\Validate'
nb_train_samples = 25
nb_validation_samples = 5
epochs = 10
my_batch_size = 10

def save_bottleneck_features():
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    # build the VGG16 network
    model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=my_batch_size,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=False)
    bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(
        generator, 
        steps=nb_train_samples // my_batch_size,
        max_queue_size=10,
        workers=1,
        use_multiprocessing=False,
        verbose=1)
    np.save(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'w'),
            bottleneck_features_train)

    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=my_batch_size,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=False)
    bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(
        generator, nb_validation_samples // my_batch_size)
    np.save(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy', 'w'),
        bottleneck_features_validation)

def train_top_model():
    train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy'))
    train_labels = np.array(
        [0] * (nb_train_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_train_samples / 2))

    validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy'))
    validation_labels = np.array(
        [0] * (nb_validation_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_validation_samples / 2))

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(train_data, train_labels,
              epochs=epochs,
              batch_size=my_batch_size,
              validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
    model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)

save_bottleneck_features()
train_top_model()
```

And this is the error I get:

```python
PS C:\Users\NSA\ownCloud\Documents\Tensorflow\Skripts> cd 'c:\Users\NSA\ownCloud\Documents\Tensorflow\Skripts'; ${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe' 'C:\Users\NSA\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.3.1\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_launcher.py' 'c:\Users\NSA\ownCloud\Documents\Tensorflow\Skripts' '50490' '34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14' 'RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput' 'c:\Users\NSA\ownCloud\Documents\Tensorflow\Skripts\first_try_real_transfer_learning_keras_vgg16.py'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will
be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
Bottleneck Features saven
2018-04-09 16:02:08.772206: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-04-09 16:02:09.345010: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce 940MX major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.189
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0
totalMemory: 2.00GiB freeMemory: 1.66GiB
2018-04-09 16:02:09.356147: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1312] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-04-09 16:02:10.108947: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1429 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce 940MX, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
Found 109 images belonging to 2 classes.
2018-04-09 16:02:16.979539: W C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.33GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2018-04-09 16:02:17.441196: W C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.19GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2018-04-09 16:02:17.792983: W C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.14GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2018-04-09 16:02:18.122577: W C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.17GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2/2 [==============================] - 4s 2s/step
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\NSA\ownCloud\Documents\Tensorflow\Skripts\first_try_real_transfer_learning_keras_vgg16.py", line 94, in <module>
    save_bottleneck_features()
  File "c:\Users\NSA\ownCloud\Documents\Tensorflow\Skripts\first_try_real_transfer_learning_keras_vgg16.py", line 56, in save_bottleneck_features
    bottleneck_features_train)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 511, in save
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 565, in write_array
    version)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 335, in _write_array_header
    fp.write(header_prefix)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
PS C:\Users\NSA\ownCloud\Documents\Tensorflow\Skripts>
```

The error occurs specifically when calling **model.predict_generator()**

At first I thought its running out of memory because my batch size is too large, but even when I use a batch size of 1 it requires over 2GiB of memory. I have installed CUDA 9.0, cuDNN 7.0, Tensorflow 1.6.0 and Keras 2.1.5 using TensorFlow backend. This used to work without issue but it suddenly started giving me this error. I'm using a NVIDIA GeForce 940MX

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with memory or tensorflow. A file opened as text is being written bytes.
Instead of opening the file as text:

```
open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'w')
```

open it as bytes:

```
open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'wb')
```

This applies to all the calls to `open` you have.